# queryRecord returns a class object instead of the record I expect

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I'm using `ember-cli-mirage` to stub out the API, in the config I have this

```
this.get('/users',function(db,request){
  if(request.queryParams.short_url){
    var short_url = request.queryParams.short_url;
    return db.users.where({short_url: short_url});
  } else {
    console.log('no query params');
    return db.users;
  }
});
```

In my index route I have the model hook setup as such

```
model(params) {
  return this.store.queryRecord('user',{short_url: params.short_url});
}
```

But that's not returning me my user model from mirage, when I cast that to a variable and log it to the console I get a class object instead.

Comment: You want to use it in template or what?

Comment: I actually don't care to use it in the template here, I'm going to store some info from it in local storage but in the future I may want to use in the template for this or a similar query.

Answer (score 1):

What [`store.queryRecord`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_queryRecord) returns is a promise. Ember internally waits for that to resolve before rendering the template. If you want to log that or persist that data into localstorage, you'll need to resolve that promise first

```
// ...
return this.store.queryRecord('user',{short_url: params.short_url}).then(function(result){
    // console.log(result);
    // localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(result));
    return result;
});
// ...
```

Comment: Still returning undefined, maybe this is a mirage issue? I pushed it to a github repo for reference https://github.com/Jordan4jc/temp-bidr-app